# No permitir ingresar espacios en VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb

Lo que deseo es no permitir que se ingresen espacios en un textbox,pero no lo logro ,he intentado con un evento IsWhiteSpace

```
  Private Sub TextBox5_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox5.KeyPress
    If Char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = False
    ElseIf Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = False
    Else
        e.Handled = True
        MsgBox("No se permiten espacios", , "ALERTA")
    End If
End Sub
```

Pero logro lo contrario ,que solo se ingresen espacios

Gracias

Comment: Con no ingresar espacios, ¿te refieres a la tecla `space` o a todo tipo de espacios (copiar un texto con espacios, por ejemplo)?

Comment: ingresar espacios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que esto te ayude, saludos!

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Textbox1.KeyPress
                'Si es separador...
                If Char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar) Then
                'Que anule la entrada de texto y aparezca un msgbox.
                    MsgBox("No se puden ingresar espacios.")
                    e.Handled = True
                End If
            End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda , ya pude probar tu sugerencia y funciona muy bien ,de hecho la tome como solucion Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Despues de probar algunas cosas lo logre de la siguiente forma ,acepta todo menos espacios

```
   Private Sub TextBox5_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox5.KeyPress
    If Char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = False
        If Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = False
        ElseIf Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = False
        Else
            e.Handled = True
            MsgBox("No se permiten espacios", , "ALERTA")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Hice las pruebas y funciona como quiero

Comment: Tienes un if anidado con tres casos, dos de los cuales nunca se van a dar (un espacio en blanco no puede ser número a la vez, por ejemplo), por lo que tu código aunque funcione, no es correcto. Échale un ojo a las respuestas que te han dado, modifica tu código en consecuencia, y acepta una de ellas para ayudar a las personas que se encuentren con este problema en el futuro.

Comment: Gracias si voy a revisar

Answer (score 1):

Creo que para lo que buscas, esto es suficiente:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If (Not e.KeyChar <> " "c) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Visto tu código, parece que el código que buscas sería simplemente:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If Char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
        MsgBox("No se permiten espacios", , "ALERTA")
    End If
End Sub
```